# What is the chart type where instead of coloured standard area corresponding to value, a label text size itself serves as visual indicator

Tags: charts

If we take a look at [PYPL programming index](http://pypl.github.io/PYPL.html) showing popularity over Google trends, we can see a picture chart like where higher value entries have bigger text label drawn? I.e "Python" is the biggest.

What is the name of this chart? As all my Google search results end up all over the place but nowhere close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean what the name of that type of chart is? Because this specific one is clearly labelled, “PYPL PopularitY of Programming Language.”

Or do you mean this graphic shown below?

[image: “PYPL PopularitY of Programming Language” tag cloud image.]

That is called a “[tag cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud).” As Wikipedia describes it:

> A tag cloud (word cloud, or weighted list in visual design) is a novelty visual representation of text data, typically used to depict keyword metadata (tags) on websites, or to visualize free form text. Tags are usually single words, and the importance of each tag is shown with font size or color. This format is useful for quickly perceiving the most prominent terms and for locating a term alphabetically to determine its relative prominence. When used as website navigation aids, the terms are hyperlinked to items associated with the tag.